# SQL stored procedure that returns a boolean value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
AS
BEGIN    
DECLARE @true BIT, @false BIT;
SET @true = 1;
SET @false = 0;

IF (some condition)
    Select @true;
ELSE
    Select @false;
END
```

SQL is not the language that I'm strongest in now, but the above stored procedure seems to be produce the desired functioning: returning the truth value of `some condition`.

Is there a better way to define this stored procedure?  By the way, it runs on MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Since SQL Server has no Boolean data type, and since the bit values 1 and 0 are widely used and understood to represent true and false in many programming languages, I would simply return `0x1` or `0x0` as appropriate. I don't think that actually declaring `@true` and `@false` variables adds anything to the code.

What might add something would be to return the value in an [output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a useful name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
    @IsTrue BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN    

IF (condition)
    SET @IsTrue = 0x1
ELSE
    SET @IsTrue = 0x0
END
```

Especially if your procedure is called from other TSQL code, it is much easier to use an output parameter in the calling code than a result set. But if you're calling it from some other language then you can make that decision based on the calling language and framework. An output parameter is the preferred way to return scalar values from a procedure: use `SELECT` for returning result sets and `RETURN` for indicating the status of the procedure execution itself (succeeded, failed, failed with reason X etc.).

And by 'useful name' I mean a name that indicates that the purpose of the variable is to store a true/false condition. Names starting with `Is` or `Has` are usually good. But please do not use a double-negative name: something like `if @IsNotEnabled = 0x0` is extremely difficult to parse mentally without interrupting your thoughts. `IsEnabled = 0x1` is far better.

And depending on your condition, you might be able to use `CASE`:

```
SET @result = CASE WHEN (condition) THEN 0x1
              ELSE 0x0
              END
```

Whether or not that's preferable in this specific case is probably a question of taste, but `CASE` seems more 'SQL-like' to me. But `IF` and `CASE` do different things so you can't always substitute one for the other.